# does sitecore support WebP or AVIF images

Tags: media-library

I am looking at a requirement where webp image support is expected.
Does Sitecore 10.2 support webp or avif images.

I tried uploading a webp to the media library and it seems to upload. but when I create a media field i am unable to select the webp image from the media library
thanks

Comment: Are you working with a CDN like Cloudflare? That product can take existing images and convert to webp automatically.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the media library does not support modern image formats such as WebP, AVIF. Dianoga is an extension that provides a solution.

Check this one: [Sitecore not allowing WebP image to attached in an image field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19834/sitecore-not-allowing-webp-image-to-attached-in-an-image-field)

I hope this helps!

Comment: If there is a duplicate question/answer - please flag the question, don't answer with a link to the duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: I have written a blog to enable Sitecore cms to upload webp images.

**https://mastersitecore.blogspot.com/2022/02/how-to-upload-webp-image-in-sitecore-cms.html**